# autocomplete boost program options

Tags: bash, autocomplete, boost-program-options, bash-completion, compgen

after hours of search I ended up writing my first stackoverflow question.

I want to create a completion function for a bash script, so far so good ;).
This bash script calls other executables that have their own autocompletion.

Example:

```
$ my_script foo par
  # calls /usr/local/libexec/my_script/foo par
```

Autocompleting the first parameter of my_script (in this case "foo") works, because the possible options are the files in the folder "/usr/local/libexec/my_script/".
Each program in this folder does have a working auto completion, which was a byproduct of using boost::program_options.

I now want to implement the auto completion for the next parameters of my_script by referencing to the auto completion of the program gooing to be called.

```
$ my_script foo <tab>
  # should output possible options to the foo subcommand
  # like /usr/local/libexec/my_script/foo <tab>
```

I've started by this answer [Bash completion from another completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231639/bash-completion-from-another-completion), but *_command* or *_command_offset 1* does not seem to work for me.

- How can I get the options of *foo*, and how can I use this in my_script?

My current */etc/bash_completion.d/my_script* looks like the following

```
_my_script()
{
  local cur prev opts
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

  if [[ "$COMP_CWORD" == 1 ]]; then
    # 1. param: for program to be loaded
    for i in $( ls /usr/local/libexec/my_script/ ); do
      opts="${opts} ${i} "
    done
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" ${cur}) )
  else
    # next param: of the program to be loaded

    # how do I get the options of "foo" here?        

  fi

  return 0
}
complete -F _my_script my_script
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I read your question, the completion of `sudo` and `git` came to my mind. They both have the similar behavior you desired. So I looked for their completion functions. Here are your missing lines:

```
local root_command=${COMP_WORDS[0]}
_command_offset 1
```

It's copied from `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo` in Ubuntu 16.04. I totally don't knows its meaning. But it works.